# Absolute Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

Prove that if $\vert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \vert \leq \vert \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} \vert $ for $ n >>1$, and $\sum b_n$ is absolutely convergent, then $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent.

My attempt at a solution:

By the Comparison Theorem, since $\vert \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} \vert $ converges by hypothesis, and since $\vert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \vert \leq \vert \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} \vert $, then $\sum a_n$ must also converge.

Questions:

I know this is valid if $b_n$ is not equal to 1. However, how would I proceed to prove this in the case where it is equal to 1? Would I be able to make an estimate using the given information about $b_n$ being absolutely convergent?

Thanks in advance, I greatly appreciate suggestions/feedback/advice.

I am using the textbook *Introduction to Analysis* by Arthur Mattuck.

Comment: Why does $|\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} |$ converge?

Comment: At first, I thought that because $b_n$ was convergent, then so would $ \vert \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} \vert $, but I think that I can see how this is quite misleading and perhaps even incorrect.

Comment: Take the sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$, then create the series with terms $(a_1,\frac{a_1}{1}, a_2,\frac{a_2}{2},\cdots, a_{n},\frac{a_{n}}{{n}},\cdots)$. A little work shows that the ratios of successive terms is unbounded above.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little on how $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ can then be used to create the sequence of successive terms? The way I would see it, isn't $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ bounded below by 0?

Comment: I added some text to my answer to elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hint:

You have some $N$ such that For $n \ge N$, $| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} | \le | \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} | $.

Then for $n > N$ (notice the strict inequality),  and we have $\frac{a_{n}}{a_N} = \frac{a_{N+1}}{a_{N}} \cdots \frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}$, and similarly for the $b_n$.

So $|a_n| \le |a_N| |\frac{a_{N+1}}{a_{N}}| \cdots | \frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}} | \le |a_N| |\frac{b_{N+1}}{b_{N}}| \cdots | \frac{b_{n}}{b_{n-1}} | = |a_N| |\frac{b_{n}}{b_{N}}| = | \frac{a_N}{b_N} | |b_n|$.

**Addendum**: To see why $|\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}|$ does not necessarily converge, consider the following:

It is straightforward to see (because of the $\frac{1}{n^2}$ form) that $b_n = \begin{cases} \frac{4}{n^2}, & n \text{ even} \\ \frac{8}{n(n+1)^2}, & n \text{ odd} \end{cases}$ is a convergent series.

If $n$ is odd, we have $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} = \frac{n}{2}$, and hence $\limsup_n \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} = \infty$. (And since $\liminf_n \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} = 0$, the ratio does not converge.)

Comment: Ok, I believe I can understand this. At the end of the answer, could $| \frac{a_N}{b_N} | |b_n|$ be used in order show that since $|b_n|$ is convergent (by hypothesis) then, the product is also convergent? Thank you very much @copper.hat for this response.

Comment: Yes; basically it reduces to the comparison test.

Answer (score 1):

@copper.hat Given $\sum b_n$ is absolutely convergent we must have at least $\lim_{n\to\infty} |\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}|\leq 1$. There are absolutely convergent series with $\lim_{n\to\infty} |\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}| = 1$ so we can't say more than that without more information. But, none the less, $|\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}|$ converges.

Apologies for this mistake and also for posting this as an answer. I had thought I was just posting a comment, but it appears as I'm new to Stack Exchange I'd missed the fact that I don't have the reputation to post comments. My arrival is heralded with various blunders!!

Comment: That is not true.

Comment: @ copper.hat It's called the ratio test. If $\lim_{n\to\infty} |\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}| > 1$ then the $\sum b_n$ diverges. But we are given that $\sum b_n$ converges absolutely.

Comment: The ratio test is a sufficient condition for convergence, not necessary.

Comment: I added an example showing why this is not so. The ratio need not have a limit.

Comment: My apologies, as I'd forgotten about the case where the ratio limit doesn't exist still being inconclusive. So your example is equivalent to $\sum \frac{1}{n^2} + \sum\frac{1}{n^3}$ which we know converges but terms like $\left|\frac{\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}}{\frac{1}{n^3}}\right|$ are a problem.

Comment: No worries. That would have been a much simpler example than my construction.

Comment: I found this a useful and enjoyable conversation. This is generally how things turn out when discussing maths with your peers. I'd like to thank copper.hat for his humility and hope I didn't offend anyone. @copper.hat I liked your answer but I don't have the reputation to click the useful arrow. I will try to remember to come back and do so.  - Cheers

Comment: Geoff, no problem at all, I'm happy if I able to help.